# It is possible to check if a time (no date) is in specific datetime interval?

Tags: r, datetime

Example: I want to check if 03:00 is inside interval of 2015-01-05 00:52 and 2015-01-05 05:52, for this case my desirable outcome is to be TRUE.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Things given are insufficient. Please elaborate. Whether the values to be compared are stored in dataframe/atomic vector/list??

Comment: The values are stored in a dataframe. I tried to check this condition with the following code:

`start_curfew="2000-01-02 00:00:00"

end_curfew="2000-01-02 05:59:00"

format(as.POSIXct("2015-02-05 03:24"),'%H:%M')>format(as.POSIXct(start_curfew),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')&format(as.POSIXct("2015-02-05 03:24"),'%H:%M')>format(as.POSIXct(end_curfew),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`

Comment: I was asking if there is any simple way to check the condition above, dataframe for the case is almost irrelevant

Comment: @JoséCampelo think of it this way - you are asking is 03:00 (some text?) between two dates with time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution for a data frame with several max and min datetimes (solution is shorter than the number of lines for creating a reproducible example):

```
# Reproducible example
set.seed(666)
timeLimits <- seq(from = (as.POSIXct("1996-6-6 06:06:06")),
                  to = (as.POSIXct("1997-6-6 06:06:06")),
                  by = "hour")
timeLimits <- matrix(data = sort(sample(x = timeLimits, size = 66)), 
                     ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
timeLimits <- data.frame(min = as.POSIXct(x = timeLimits[,1], origin = "1970-1-1 00:00:00"),
                         max = as.POSIXct(x = timeLimits[,2], origin = "1970-1-1 00:00:00"))


# The solution
require(lubridate)

answer <- apply(timeLimits, 2, as.character)
answer <- apply(timeLimits, 1, function(x) is.element(3, hour(seq(as.POSIXct(x[1]), as.POSIXct(x[2]), "hour"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**update**

```
library(data.table)
as.ITime("03:00") %in% as.ITime( seq( as.POSIXct("2015-01-04 22:52"), 
                                      as.POSIXct("2015-01-05 05:52"),
                                      by = 1 ) )
#[1] TRUE
```

**old answer**

```
as.ITime("03:00") %between% c(as.ITime("2015-01-05 00:52"), 
                              as.ITime("2015-01-05 05:52"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However when the start_curfew is different the condition is not true.

`as.ITime("03:00") %between% c(as.ITime("2015-01-04 22:52"), 
                              as.ITime("2015-01-05 05:52"))`

And the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below by playing some tricks on `string`s

```
> match(x, sort(c(x, gsub(".*\\s", "", c(start, end))))) == 2
[1] TRUE
```

where

```
start <- "2015-01-05 00:52"
end <- "2015-01-05 05:52"
x <- "3:00"
```